# how to import python variable to bash

Tags: python, bash, variables

I have two scripts:
Python:

```
if canceled==True:
   os.environ["c"] = "0"
if canceled==False:
   os.environ["c"] = "1"
```

Bash:

```
kill_jobs()
{
    pkill -TERM -P "$BASHPID"
    echo $c
    if [ $c == "0" ]
    then
    echo -e "OPERATIONS CANCELED"
    elif [ $c == "1" ]
    then
    echo -e "OPERATIONS FINISHED"
    fi
}
trap kill_jobs EXIT
```

How can I do to pass a python variable to bash script ?
(My level in bash is near to 0 ...)
Thanks

Edit: Now I have this error: (in french)

```
[: == : opérateur unaire attendu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try:

```
os.environ["c"] = "value"
```

You can set it this way, I guess

[Refer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

Comment: ok, your solution seems to work. I have another problem, I will edit my question.

Comment: either `if [ $c -eq 0 ]` or `if [ "$c" == "0" ]`. Please ask one question in one post. I haven't set this standard, but I guess that is what everyone follow here.

Answer (score 0):

The python script should end with:

```
print c
```

Then you use it in bash with:

```
c=$(python_script)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no need to pass in environment variable ?

Comment: No, just use ordinary shell variables. Environment variables are inherited by child processes.